# Framework or tools for build wsdl with java

Tags: java, web-services, wsdl

Is there any excellent tool in JAVA to deal with webservice or wsdl?

Comment: `to deal with webservice or wsdl?` elaborate

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Yes. There is a standardized API ([JAX-WS](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/JAX-WS)) that is even integrated into the Java standard API (the `javax.xml.ws` packages) since Java 6, and multiple implementations thereof, such as [Axis](http://axis.apache.org/axis/) and [CXF](http://cxf.apache.org/).

Answer (score 1):

If you are using Eclipse try [Eclipse Web Tools Platform Project](http://www.eclipse.org/projects/project_summary.php?projectid=webtools), it's good at my point of view and sufficient for me.

For IntelliJIDEA Web Services [link](http://www.jetbrains.com/idea/features/java_web_services.html)

Comment: @DYun see edited answer it contains intellij link hope it helps.

Comment: perfect link, i am going to have a try.

Comment: I just got the java object from the wsdl via the intellij webservice component :)

Answer (score 1):

Read about **wsimport** utility, which generates client-support code from the WSDL document (or URL pointing at service endpoint).

Comment: It should be noted that `wsimport` (as well as `wsgen` if you want to go the other way around) are part of JAX-WS.

Answer (score 1):

If you're a Spring user, I'd recommend the Spring web service module.  It makes using WSDL, creating web services, and implementing clients easy.