# Is that a good way to make webservice work with resin?

Tags: java, web-services, resin

I asked a question yesterday [Question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5309366/framework-or-tools-for-build-wsdl-with-java) about the framework or tools dealing with webservice in java, I am appreciate the answers. I tried some ways and I decide to use axis for the client and JAX-WS for the server side. But i am confusing that is that a good way to server the webservice with resin or can webservice work well with resin?

Answer (score 0):

```
Maybe EJB3 will help you. Resin supports it.
```

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure if I understand your question, but is this what you are looking for?

[a jax-ws service for the resin soa](http://www.caucho.com/resin-3.1/examples/soa-jaxws/index.xtp)

The article uses JAX-WS (standard java api) to create the web service. You specify a web service endpoint in a class using `@WebService` annotation. More on JAX-WS [here](http://download.oracle.com/javaee/5/tutorial/doc/bnayn.html).